# Running Zend with XAMPP on Windows 10 - connect to database

Tags: windows, zend-framework, xampp, phpstorm, mariadb

I have a problem learning Zend, hope you can help me. Much approchiato, some evenings lost...

I am following [this](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/) tutorial and reach an article about a table creation. I am using XAMPP v3.2.2 and in the PhpStorm I can connect to its MariaDB database using a Database panel.
However when I attempt to run the php script `load_db` described there, it creates a database in my `/data` folder.

How can I connect it to the XAMPP database? I guess I need to run some MariaDB script in order to connect to the actual database, however I was unable to ask Google a correct question I guess.

I think I am missing something totally obvious, I hope you can push me in the right way.

Comment: Figured it out yet?

Comment: Noup, did other stuff... I need to dig in it again...

Comment: It's a bit dated, but give [this tutorial](https://keet.me/31/tutorials/setting-up) of mine a shot. I've been told there's some mistakes in there, but you should be able to figure those out ;) Linked chapter is environment setup (Windows 10 + Xampp + Windows hosts file, etc)